# ggarrange --> how to get rid of plot legends

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to make a figure with three boxplots comparing three different variables in the same four groups.

Because in all three comparisons I compare the same groups, one legend would suffice.

I managed to succesfully get rid of the legends in  (two of the three) the plots by adding

```
plot + theme ( legend.title = element_blank(), 
legend.position ="none")
```

to the script.

However, when I try to combine them into one figure using ggarrange, all the legends reappear next to the plots, leaving me with a a figure where the legend is effectively repeated three times.

Anyone knows an explanation or a solution?
(I am happy to provide more info, if needed).

It'd be great if I could avoid just cutting out the extra legends in a graphical software, and have the desired figure done entirely in R.

NOTE: I cannot facet wrap the plots, because they all have different scales.

Comment: You can use facet_wrap with different scales. Just use the `scales = c("free")` argument. For anything more detailed, we'll need a minimal reproducible example ;)

Comment: @Mandarc Have you set the ggarrange() argument 'common.legend' = True ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two packages with a `ggarrange()` function: ggpubr and egg. You can do it easily with ggpubr: `ggarrange(plot1, plot2, plot3, common.legend = TRUE)`. Don't know if it works the same with the egg package.